# Error message show in wrong place

Tags: html, css

[image: wrong position of the error]

If the date is not fill, it will shows the error message as above,

I am using

```
 <div><p>
    <label class="field">Event Start</label>
    <input type="date" name="sDate" min="2016-04-30" required></input>  
    </p></div>
```

and here is my css for the label

```
label   {width: 20%;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 4%;
    font-weight:bold;   }
```

but it pop up in wrong place, it should show be right exact at the date there.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure that your validation message is a label, yet you're showing us your css for a label. You may want to look into that further.

Comment: How is that error message generated? is it a jQuery script? Os generated? Browser generated? please specify.

Comment: Inputs are self-closing. There is no `</input>`

Comment: That looks like a default browser warning and can't be styled. The `label` element has nothing to do with it.

Comment: YOu need to make a jsfiddle or sniper for proved your problem .